# isLocationOnPath() android google map?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps, google-polyline

In my `onLocationChanged` I am using from :

```
boolean isOnRoute = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(ltln, pointList, false, 10.0f);
```

But crash me and say :

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, I am working on a similar kind of project in which i am drawing a line between two points on google map using https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android library. Now, I have a certain set of coordinates fetched from database and I want to check whether that coordinates lies on that polyline or not with 5m of tolerance. Can you please help me or please send your code at rajgar114@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

use the flowing library to get rid of this problem.

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
```

Comment: I am drawing Polyline without error but when I am using from isLocationOnPath get me crash.In my project I added compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' too.

Comment: if you use `0.4+` then you will get this error. user `0.3+` it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using correct Gradle dependancy:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

and you still have this problem, try to "Clean" the Android Studio project by selecting "Build: -> "Clean Project".